# Automatic field numbering in String formatting

Tags: java

I am trying to format String in java using `MessageFormat` class. The String contains positional field but it only work if I provide the field number. For e.g

`MessageFormat.format("{0} {1}", "Hi", "Java")` works but

`MessageFormat.format("{} {}", "Hi", "Java")` gives

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: 
    at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1429)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:479)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:362)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:840)
    at controller.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1427)
```

Is there a way(any other class or library) in that it can handle both automatic and manual field numbering something like python does?

```
In [3]: print "{} {}".format("Hi", "Java")
Hi Java

In [4]: print "{0} {1}".format("Hi", "Java")
Hi Java
```

Comment: If you don't want to provide indices, then use `String.format` instead.

Comment: Yes I could do that but have an use case where i can get string with or without indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @JohnH answer, String.format could do automatic and manual field indices for formatting String.

```
String.format("%s %s", "Hi", "Java")
String.format("%1$s %2$s %1$s", "Hi", "Java")
```

[Reference Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

It's not ergonomic than `"{1} {2}"` but gets the job done.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following hack:

```
String.format("{} {}".replace("{}", "%s"), new String[]{"Hi", "Java"}));
```

It first replaces `{}` with `%s`, then replace each `%s` with the corresponding value from the String array you provide as an argument for [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method.

Note that since `format` accepts `Object... args` as the second argument, you can write:

```
String.format("{} {}".replace("{}", "%s"), "Hi", "Java");
```

Comment: Yes this will work but not what I want. Also this will not help in positional indices of args.

Comment: @barunsthakur You have to check which version you need to use. Try a regex for that.

Answer (score 3):

I use slf4j for logging, which enables you to log a string like so:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("name").debug("{} {}", "Hello", "World");
```

Just took a look at the source code to see what this used to format the string, and it uses this class:

```
org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter
```

There are 3 methods available here. 1 for substituting a single object:

```
MessageFormatter.format(String message, Object arg);
```

One to substitute 2 objects:

```
MessageFormatter.format(String message, Object arg1, Object arg2);
```

And one to substitute an array of objects:

```
MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(String message, Object[] argArray);
```

These all return an object of type `FormattingTuple`. To get the formatted string from the object, you should call `FormattingTuple.getMessage();`

To use this alongside manual field numbering, take a look at the below method:

```
public String formatString(String original, Object... replacements) {
    String stringToReturn = original;
    for (int i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
        stringToReturn = stringToReturn.replaceAll("\\{" + i + "\\}", replacements[i].toString());
    }
    return MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(stringToReturn, replacements).getMessage();
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(MessageFormatter.format("{1} {2} {1}", "hi", "java").getMessage());` outputs `{1} {2} {1}`.

Comment: Your question indicates that you wanted to do this without specifying the positional field. 

`System.out.println(MessageFormatter.format("{} {}", "hi", "java").getMessage());` outputs `hi java`

Comment: No. "that it can handle automatic and manual field numbering"

Comment: Just edited my answer with a quick method I wrote to handle both cases.

Comment: Yes this can work but is a workaround and what i wanted is a standard library or something doing it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the pattern posted by Maroun Maroun if I was confined to standard libraries like barunsthakur.

Ben Greens clever idea is useful for everyone who uses sfl4j when logging with non-indexed arguments, in addition to preparing strings manually with indexed arguments.

There was one disadvantage for me:
I can use both indexed and non-indexed arguments now, but I'm not able to use the FormatType and FormatStyle options from java.text.MessageFormat.format(), e.g. {0,number,currency}.

So I made up an extended version of Ben's solution, that utilizes all 3 variants.

```
import org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public static String format(String original, Object... replacements)
{
    if (Pattern.matches(".*\\{\\d+,.+,.+\\}.*", original))
    {
        return MessageFormat.format(original, replacements);
    }
    else
    {
        String r = "\\{\\d\\}";

        if(original.matches(".*" + r + ".*"))
        {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(original);
            StringBuffer b = null;
            int i = 0;

            while(m.find())
            {
                if(b == null) b = new StringBuffer();
                m.appendReplacement(b, replacements[i].toString());
                i++;
            }
            m.appendTail(b);
            return (i > 0) ? b.toString() : null;
        }
        else
        {
            return MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(original, replacements).getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Unit-Tests:

```
String expected = "pink is a disgusting color";
String actual = StringHelpers.format("{0} is a disgusting {1}", "pink", "color");
assertEquals(expected, actual);

expected = "01-02-2017 was a rather meh day";
actual = StringHelpers.format("{0,date,MM-dd-YYYY} was a rather {1} day", new Date(117,0,2), "meh");
assertEquals(expected, actual);

expected = "One Person expects the danish inquisition";
actual = StringHelpers.format("{} expects the {} inquisition", "One Person", "danish");
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is what you're looking for.

```
String foo = String.format("%s %s", "Hi", "Java")
StringBuffer bar = new StringBuffer(foo);
```